# VBA: match of a variable range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem. For a certain spreadsheet I want to find out the position (only column) of a value smaller than threshold (further called maxt). I have to solve this in VBA as I need them on a different worksheet to give out accumulated numbers.

I am able to retrieve the max smaller than threshold but the vba match function gives back an error that the number couldnt be found.
However, if the value maxt is copied to a cell and I use the the normal match function on the sheet with the cell containing maxt as condition (=MATCH(cell of maxt; range), it works without any issues.

Problem (I only have A to C filled in my example; irrelevant as it doesnt work on only a few constellations).

A  B  C

8  5  6    -> doesn't work (Error: 1004)

5  6  7    -> works

7  6  7    -> works

4  8  5    -> works

Below is the code.

```
Dim myVar As Double
Dim myVarAdress As Long

For I = 1 To 10
myVar = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(A" & I & ":M" & I & "<6, A" & I & ":M" & I &   "))")
myVarAdress = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myVar, Range("A" & I & ":M" & I))

Next I

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change `myVarAdress = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myVar, Range("A" & I & ":M" & I))`
to `myVarAdress = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myVar, Range("A" & I & ":M" & I), 0)`
That "0" means that you are looking for the exact match. Also you should add a conditon that will skip the 0 value of your "myVar" variable. For example:

```
If myVar > 0 Then
    myVarAdress = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myVar, Range("A" & i & ":M" & i), 0)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup has a couple of different problems that must be addressed before a true solution can be found.

1) You are trying to evaluate a MAX() function, that only has one argument. Your IF() function will either return a value less than 6, or FALSE (0). So either your MAX() function is irrelevant, your IF() function is irrelevant, or you left out one or more arguments on either/both of those functions. In any case, there is no set behavior for what to do when there is no item less than 6 in a row. This raises the possibility that myVar is 0, which is likely to cause faulty results because:

2) You left off the third argument in the MATCH() function. Because your range is (currently) larger than your data set, when you leave off the third argument for MATCH() it will fail any time the data is not organized correctly. This is particularly problematic when you are returning FALSE from your IF() function (treated as 0 by MAX()) because MATCH() is matching to the blanks in your data. Which means that the size of your data set **does** matter. If you had all 13 rows filled in, your first line would (probably) not fail, but it would not actually match to the 5 you want it to if there were any values LOWER than 5 to the right of column B. Also, it potentially causes some of the other lines to fail if suddenly there aren't any values below 6 in any of the columns *and* there are no blanks for MATCH() to find and treat as a 0.

All that being said, without further clarification of how you want to clean up these problems, here is a proposed solution (that assumes you want the first occurrence of your max value less than 6, regardless of how many occurrences there are):

```
Sub MatchSub()

Dim myVar As Double
Dim myVarAdress As Long

Dim rngMaxT As Range

Dim wsFindMax As Worksheet
Set wsFindMax = ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To 10
    myVar = Evaluate("=IF(A" & i & ":M" & i & "<6, A" & i & ":M" & i & ")")
    Set rngMaxT = wsFindMax.UsedRange.Rows(i)
    If rngMaxT(1, 1).Value = myVar Then
        myvaraddress = 1
    Else
        Set rngMaxT = rngMaxT.Find(myVar, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False)
        If rngMaxT Is Nothing Then
            'There is no value in the row less than 6
        Else
            myVarAdress = rngMaxT.Column
        End If
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```